# get textview.getHeight() in onCreate() method

Tags: android

## activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:onClick="aaaa"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:id="@+id/tv10"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

## MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView tv10;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv10=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv10);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "H: "+tv10.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void aaaa(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "H: "+tv10.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

*When i press on Test Button "tv10.getHeight()" give me the value of TextView Height, But onCreate() method "tv10.getHeight()" gives 0 of TextView Height. *
**I need TextView Height into onCreate() method**

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code :

```
         textview.post(new Runnable() {
                              public void run() {
```

```
                                 int height = textview.getHeight();
```

```
                              }
                      });
```